# How to scrape the contents of the page using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am trying to copy the contents in one of the page in my website and paste it in a file. I can post a sample text stored in a variable from angular and save it in a file in the back end using node express. So I have no issues in writing a file.

But how can I send the whole contents of the page to the back end? Thanks

Comment: `var my_content = document.body.innerHTML` ?

Comment: @dev-null Nope. It copies all the markup instead of only the contents

Comment: `document.body.textContent`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help

```
document.body.innerHTML.toString()
```

Edit : Above method will get you the template + content. If you need only the content go for

```
document.body.textContent
```